# Different between "have been doing "and"have being done"

Tags: active-vs-passive

I'm always confused about this tow construction
I confronted this sentences and cant undrestand the main meaning
-There has been growing concern by researchers.
I want to know are these constructions correct?
1.John has been doing this job for ten years
2. This job has been doing by John for 10 years
If yes what is their tense

Answer (score 3):

(2) is not a valid English sentence. If you want to put the emphasis on the job rather than the person, you could say 'This job has been *done* by John for ten years.'

Neither is 'have being done' valid.

*Growing*, here, is used like an adjective to describe *concern.* The meaning is "Researchers have been feeling more and more concerned."

Comment: I am somewhat confused with 'This job has been done by John for ten years.'. Is it the same thing as 'This job has been done by John IN ten years' i.e the job is done by now and it has taken John ten years to complete it or is it something different?

Comment: I meant _job_ in the sense of _position_ or _occupation_, not a single task. 'John has been employed in this capacity for ten years.'

Comment: @AndreyChernukha  Why are you confused by "has been done by John" but not confused by "John has been doing"?